# pentaho slow rows process

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have an input table whit 170.000 records to transform on my step.
each record have a time duration, specifically on days, the JS step check this duration for example if the records has the `ini_date(2011/01/01) - end_date(2020/01/01)` the JS will create aprox 3000 rows just for that record *(the output brings 170.000 records whith different ranges... some of them have a 9 year duration)*

1. the transformation takes almost 5:30 hours to be completed.
2. on the JS STEP write over 100.000.000 rows
3. then group them

At first i used only the js step to make this tasks using join step, select value step, sort rows step and stufs. Then some of the "Data transformations" i split them usgin "calculator step", thinking that this will improve the process time but i got the same processing time

i just want to have a lower time of processing from 5 hours to one or 2 at least but the numbers of created rows in the transformation is too big to make it. Remember if a record have a 9 year period generate 3000 rows aprox, and this is just for one. knowing that the input step brings 170.000 records and differents ranges.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Do you really need to have one output record per day for each input record or are you doing that to create sums/averages per day?

Comment: Would be nice to know what your JS step is doing, and also, before the Group by step, use a 'Sort Rows' step to make sure your aggregation is correct, by default, use the same Columns used in Sort Rows step in the Group Field of the Group By step.

Comment: my js step make some data transformations like parse some types from date 2 string, split strings, make some numbers divitions, multiplications and put this results for each rows that my for statement is placed..  `for(var i=0; i<=days_total1-1; i++)` **this is my for statement, it has diferents values to iterate(3000, 2000,1000,500 etc)**  ||| `var row = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size())
  var idx = getInputRowMeta().size()

  row[idx++] = days_total-1                                                
                putRow(row)
` **this is how i put the data on each row**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JS step is producing around 100M rows your ETL is running at about 5.5k rows per second. It's not fast, but not that slow either.

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve, it would be nice to see what the group by is doing.

But, regardless, here's a few ideas to make it faster:

1. Creating new rows in JS is particularly slow and should be avoided. You're better off doing a days between dates calculation using the calculator step, then using clone row to create the row replicas you want. You can add a "clone number" field, which gives you a counter for each duplicated row, so that a subsequent calculator step can do things like add the counter to the start date.
2. If you're grouping rows the input must be sorted by the group keys, otherwise you get unexpected results.
3. When you run the transformation, where is the bottleneck? You can see in the step metrics tab the Input/Output column, which measures how full the input and output buffers of each step are. A bottleneck is usually identified by looking for a step with a full input buffer (default is 10k rows) and an empty output buffer. So, if the JS step is the slowest, you'll see its input buffer at 10k, and all input and output buffers upstream also showing 10k rows, whereas all input and output buffers downstream will be empty or almost empty.
4. In the end, if you're writing to a database, the output is expected to never be as fast as processing rows internally in PDI. 5k rows per second is usually a good performance and it's hard to improve significantly. You can, however, stop using the Table output step and instead use a bulk loader. Most database bulk loaders need the data to be written to a file, but the MySQL one can be used with a FIFO, in Mac or Linux (doesn't work in Windows)

Comment: hi, zorry for the late answer but i was out. i did your calculator suggestion and obtained the counter but now i want to increase each day according the counter value (counter=5 ---> plus 5 to the date). i only see operations between dates no date plus number

Comment: dont worry i alrady find it , thanks for your answer, i will see if the row process decrase, thanks for all

Comment: The calculator step has operations such as "Date A + B days" where A is a date field and B is an integer. You can also add other time intervals. So, Calculator to determine how many clones; Clone row to create them with clone number, then calculator again to add the clone number to the reference date.

Comment: and if i want to trunc a day to "1" the is a way to do it in the calculator step?  before all i trunc the date on my JavaScript step whit the trundate() function

Comment: It’s possible, but cumbersome. You’re better off doing it in Javascript or a user defined java class.

Comment: actually i obtained (all in the calculator step) the day of the date and i divided the number by himself and i obtained "1" and work for each date that appears, his day it will by devided by the same............ Zorry for the late answer ....... and thanks ;)

Comment: i know is out of topic but i will ask it anyway, now i have incomming records 10,20,30,40 for example what i want to do (whitout JavaScript Step) is maintain the first value and then substract the "the first" to "the second" (20-10 = 10), (30 - 20 = 10) and like that ..... hope you see this ;)

Comment: Ask a new question. Your best chance is a javascript step, though.